# task scheduler is leaving tasks open

Tags: c#, bash, scheduled-tasks

I am running a bash script under cygwin on a couple of windows machine. One is windows 7 the other is windows server 2008.

My task is set to run once per day, and the action will call:

> C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe -l C:\Wrapper.SH ORDERMAN

```
C:\Wrapper.SH calls C:\Worker.SH
```

and C:\Worker.SH branches to:

```
ORDEREXE=/myc/Projects/Hsp/bin/Debug/Hsp.exe

( $ORDERMANEXE "GO" &)
exit
```

Occasionally, I get the task window is left open. If I then close that window
my "ORDERMANEXE" c# app gets killed too.

My question is twofold:

1. Why does the exit not allow all the parent windows and task to close - as it usually does.
2. Why would closing the task window kill the exe?